# What to do about "forgotten" bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Once again I've been involved in a bounty that expired and finally was auto-rewarded. From my own limited experience this seems to happen more often lately.

There's a lot of small "injustice" at Stack Overflow I can just shrug about and forget. That's an essential faculty to keep having fun there. But forgotten bounties...

I like bountied questions, because they tend to be a bit harder, tend to require a bit more in-depth answers and, I thought so, tend to be more appreciated by the OP. So usually if I decide to answer one, I take my time and try to answer before the bounty expires. Often other answers pour in before that. Even though I know I'm biased, I often think my own later answer is better, but, yeah, **it also starts attracting votes later** (if any). So in the end, other answers tend to bubble up as auto-reward candidates.

If the OP decides to accept another answer and reward the bounty to it, that's perfectly fine with me. Fair enough, sometimes other answers simply are better.

But it seems an act of utter indifference when an OP offers a bounty, then collects the answers, but subsequently never even bothers to accept an answer (or even respond to them), let alone to do the little effort to select one for the bounty. Why do people do that? They seem to get [notified often enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180524/168269). I don't believe they forget; I think they don't care. If they can't make up their minds, they could tell so. It's not a forgotten bounty, it's a **forsaken** bounty.

So, **tl;dr;** is there anything I can do if a bounty is about to expire and I'm pretty convinced that my own answer might deserve it?

Things I *didn't do*:

- Bring it to Meta while the bounty is still alive and hope for the Meta effect.
- Ask the OP in a comment to reward the bounty.
- Downvote other answers.
- "Organize" upvotes for my answer.

What I *did do*:

- Try to improve my answer (to be honest, also to bring it back into attention, but still essentially improving it).
- Respond to the OP's comments regarding the question's content (again, also trying to draw their attention).

Comment: Gert, what would you do with additional 500 rep? AFAIK you have all privileges already.

Comment: Does that matter? Stack Overflow wouldn't exist without the incentive of rep. Nevertheless, I convinced it's not for the rep alone that high-rep users keep answering questions. I think we also just *like* to give good answers and as near-normal human beings we like recognition.

Comment: You should start answering questions in [tag:windbg]. You can be happy if you get 2 upvotes on a question there... Recognition? In WinDbg, only one person has ever got a silver badge.

Comment: @ThomasWeller But that's good, that means there is a high recognition-per-vote ratio there :)

Comment: If you're talking about the question I think you're talking about, I can see that the user has previously awarded a bounty on another question, so this isn't an issue of a user who's ignoring bounties after setting them. Maybe they just didn't feel any answer deserved the bounty? I haven't looked at the content of the question or answers so I can't judge if that's the "right" decision or not, but ultimately it's the asker's decision. Plenty of answers never get accepted, and that's OK. Give it a year or two and if it's a helpful answer you'll see a trickle of upvotes to reward you.

Comment: Not bounty related, but sometimes I wish I could travel to someone's inbox and shake their shoulders "¿why.don't.you.answer.a.simple.email?"... as it is out of my control, better go to window and watch birds on the sky.

Comment: @Dave It's one question that finally made me go to meta but it happened more often. I think if a user can't choose an answer they could still leave some comment. It's this silence that bugs me. In this specific case I know exactly what's going on and I'm sure my answer is helpful. But help vampirism seems to be rampant. I see a growing number of answers pass unnoticed (seemingly). People seem to think SO has some big support center and they're entitled to get answers. And a bounty buys them a ticket for the front row.

Comment: @brasofilo I did, and the birds said: now are you watching us again? Go to meta :)

Comment: [I just feel like you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33744526/3207406) ... (and I won't even get the half of the bounty, since my answer got only one +1)

Comment: "act of utter indifference when an OP offers a bounty, then collects the answers, but subsequently never even bothers to accept an answer (or even respond to them)". This is happened to me many times over the last year.  Some of these questions were so complex that it takes days to work on.  The OP just walks away and never reposes to any inquiries. I have also noted that some of the OPs that do this never accept any answer on any of their questions.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Welcome to the club :)

Comment: @GertArnold it wasn't a club that I wanted to join, but here I am and now I'm trying figure out whether I should keep helping people or just do less answering.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I think I finally developed some discernment regarding the reason for a bounty. I think that at least 75% of them (in my SO niche) are just lazy substitutes for improving a lousy question that would otherwise have been closed. The other 25% consists of pretty well-prepared questions, often with follow-up on comments, that OP really wants to get answered. In other words, if the question is (and remains!) close-worthy it probably isn't worth answering, despite the bounty, because OP doesn't care enough, but is smart enough not to care about rep either :)

Answer (score -3):

I wish that bounties were a bit better monitored but SE is clearly trying to split the difference. There's two counterbalanced things here

- The questioner, who put their hard earned rep up to get a better answer
- The answerer, drawn by the rep (and exclusive filter), who took the time to answer

So an abandoned bounty doesn't give an explicit reward. Instead it lets the community choose (highest vote wins) and gives half the credit. It's a decent compromise where you'd probably get nothing at all.

I give you credit for at least trying to draw their attention instead of quietly resigning yourself to half credit. I'm not sure you can do anything more than ping the bounty giver via comments.

What really galls me is when you go through the trouble of answering and they withdraw the bounty instead of giving any reward (often without comment). I wish that SE forced you to at least leave a comment as to why a user withdrew the bounty. Withdrawn bounties are silent.

Comment: _"and they withdraw the bounty instead of giving any reward"_ Can you explain what you mean here? Because it's impossible to "withdraw" a bounty, as in cancel it. It's only possible to _not award it_ to anyone, and that's only possible if no answers are eligible for the auto-award mechanic.

Comment: @Kendra Maybe that's what happened. I had one I answered and the bounty just went away without any award. I assumed you could withdraw it based on that

Comment: Nope, you can't withdraw bounties. The only way for you to get your rep back from a bounty is for a moderator to cancel it, and that's rare. (I believe they only do that for questions that need to be shut down immediately.) But if your answer doesn't meet the auto-award criteria, and neither does any other, then the bounty poster can just refuse to reward it and that rep all just fades into the void.